# how to get smallest (min) & largest (max) value in a column in specific sheet using by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have problem about my code, it can't show the smallest and largest value in Column A. I don't know where is the missing or wrong code...

my program open the txt file and input the data to the excel sheet. for example the data in column A is:

```
0.23
0.19
0.19
0.13
0.15
0.18
0.19
0.25
0.25
0.22
0.13
```

and I type my code in VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim vMin, vMax
Dim mg As Range
Dim NOR, lastrow, currentrow As Long

filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text File (*.txt),*.txt", , "Select", , False)

If VarType(filetoopen) = vbBoolean Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.OpenText filetoopen, Origin _
    :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
    , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:= _
    False, Space:=False, other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1) _
    , Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
    Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'get number of rows (row with value inside)-------------
With ActiveSheet
   NOR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'GET SMALLEST & LARGEST VALUE FROM COLUMN A==========
With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = NOR

    For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
        Set mg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(currentrow)

        'if row no data then no read------------------------
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(mg) = 0 Then

        Else
            vMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("A"))
            vMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
        End If
    Next currentrow

End With

MsgBox "Minimum =  " & vMin & ", " & "Maximum =  " & vMax, vbInformation
MsgBox "last row A is = " & NOR

End Sub
```

If I run this code, the `MessageBox` can't show the minimum (smallest) value and Maximum (largest) value in column A.

I hope you can help me to solve the problem.

aaf

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code... and two thinks:

1. Applying a function to `Columns("A")´ implies all the column so
   there's no need to iterate with for.
2. In my case maybe not yours imported numbers used dot a decimal separator and my system uses comma as decimal separator so imported
   numbers were imported as text and neither ´Max´ nor ´Min´ worked
   until changed dots to commas.

So the working code could be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim vMin, vMax

Dim mg As Range

Dim NOR, lastrow, currentrow As Long

filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text File (*.txt),*.txt", , "Select", , False)

        If VarType(filetoopen) = vbBoolean Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Workbooks.OpenText filetoopen, Origin _
        :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:= _
        False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1) _
        , Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
        Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'get number of rows (row with value inside)-------------

   With ActiveSheet

   NOR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   End With

'GET SMALLEST & LARGEST VALUE FROM COLUMN A==========

With ActiveSheet

  lastrow = NOR

    'For currentrow = 2 To lastrow

    'Set mg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(currentrow)

    'if row no data then no read------------------------

    'If WorksheetFunction.CountA(mg) = 0 Then

    'Else

        vMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("A"))

        vMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

     'End If

    'Next currentrow

End With

MsgBox "Minimum =  " & vMin & ", " & "Maximum =  " & vMax, vbInformation

MsgBox "last row A is = " & NOR

End Sub
```

And the results:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer... I try it, but why the minimum value and the maximum value are 0 ?

Comment: No, the minimum value is 0.13 and the maximum 0.25, remember that my computer has comma as decimal separator... Remember to upvote and mark as answered if it does. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Friend, I confused.. how to replace the code for point as decimal separator? thank you for your help

Comment: Well, first of all take a look at regional settings... to check if your system is configured to use comma "," or dot "." as decimal separator (in my case comma) then as your source uses "." just open notepad and replace "." for "," and use the modifications i made to your script and will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that will use ADO to read the file directly, instead of having to bring it into Excel, which should be faster. The option is is less code, and should operate very fast, even for large datasets.

Code:

```
Public Sub ShowMinAndMax()
    Dim objConnection As Object: Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim objRecordset  As Object: Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Dim FolderPath    As String: FolderPath = "C:\SomeFolderHere\" ' The folderpath to the file you want to read

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                       "Data Source=" & FolderPath & ";" & _
                       "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=TabDelimited"""

    'Get the minimum and maximum value, you also need to
    'change the fileName, currently my File is Named Example.Txt. 
    'You need to update that in the SQL statement
    objRecordset.Open "SELECT Min(F1) as MinVal, Max(F1) as MaxVal FROM Example.txt", objConnection, 3

    MsgBox ("The minimum value is: " & objRecordset.Fields("MinVal") & vbCrLf & _
            "The maximum value is: " & objRecordset.Fields("MaxVal"))

    'Clean Up
    If objRecordset.State = 1 Then objRecordset.Close
    objConnection.Close
    Set objConnection = Nothing
    Set objRecordset = Nothing
End Sub
```